# Не работает import в javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, импорт

Я установил пакет через npm как обычно (npm install jquery например). Попытался импортировать пакет:

**script.js**

```
import jquery from './jquery';
```

(импорт показан примерный, я мог забыть как правильно импортировать именно jquery)

**Так вот дело не в самом пакете, а в ошибке: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module. (дочитайте до конца прежде чем скидывать тот вопрос на stack про type="module")**

**Я прописал в теге script - type="module"**

**Консоль браузера затихла, ошибок не было, но вот сама библиотека не работала, вооообще**

Я также пытался ставить "type": "module" в package.json

Сборщиков не использовал, подключал файл script.js через тег script src="src/js/script.js">

**Но все бестолку, консоль браузера писала туже самую ошибку
Однако у других все работает без каких то там type module в теге.
Напишите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема, без всяких альтернатив.
Заранее спасибо за ответ**

Comment: Сначала прочитайте, зачем нужен `import`,  `jquery` не модуль,а либа, и она не портируется, а просто подключается.

Comment: Я не про то что jquery импортирую, я импортировал другую либу (swup.js) Сначала прочитайте внизу что про jquery это пример

Comment: Ага, у меня в машине магнитола не работает, но чинил я колесо, но магнитола так и не заработала.

Comment: Я перерыл все, и спросил именно про эту проблему с outside a module. Не знаете ответ - не пишите.

Comment: А babel у вас установлен?

Comment: Не. Я говорю же у других с ванильным js работало (и с npm)

Comment: Просто не знаю как сейчас, но раньше браузеры не понимали import/export без транспилятора

Comment: а Вы тот модуль (swup.js) тоже пытались импортировать по относительном пути? примерно так `... from './swap'`?

Comment: я делал так: import Swup from './swup';

Comment: слишком мало информации: в какой именно консоли показывалась ошибка? как именно все подключается на страницу? используется ли какой-либо сборщик?

Comment: Приведи в вопросе [mcve], плюс структуру своих папок

Comment: @RavenTheX, сейчас понимают, частично

Comment: если Вы импортируете модуль из `node modules`, то не нужно указывать путь. пишите просто `import ИМЯ_ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ from 'swap' `, то есть в пути не надо указывать `./`

Answer (score 5):

Начну с того, что я не увидел слово сервер.

> Без какого либо СЕРВЕРА ***export import*** работать не будут.

Нельзя просто с проводника открыть файл `index.html` и мечтать, что будет работать, да хоть миллион раз пропиши ***`<script type="module" src="./js/index.js"></script>`***

> Атрибут  ***`type="module"`*** обязателен...

Лично я запускаю при помощи плагина  **Live Server** для редактора ***VS-Code***

Далее про волшебное слово `NPM...`

> Если просто установить например `JQ` через `npm`, то работать будет, но при условии, если путь к файлу будет абсолютный

```
import '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js';
```

---

> Далее про ***`export import`***

Для того чтобы что-то импортировать, это надо экспортировать...

Экспортировать и импортировать можно разными вариантами...

Например у нас есть `<script type="module" src="./js/index.js"></script>`
В нем и импортируем..

Есть файл `test.js` из него экспортируем...

```
export const test_1 = ['Zina', 'Leha', 'Kolay'];
export const test_2 = ['15', '25', '45'];
export const test_3 = ['Good', 'Bad', 'OK'];
export const test_4 = ['Rus', 'Geo', 'Eng'];
```

а в фале `index.js`

```
import {test_1, test_2, test_3, test_4} from './test.js';
```

---

Или можем экспортировать весь файл целиком `export default '*';`

```
function testExport(n) {
    return n + n;
}

console.log("testExport(4)", testExport(4));

function testExport_1(n) {
    return n + n;
}

console.log("testExport_1(5)", testExport_1(5));


export default '*';
```

А импортируем просто файл

```
import './test-2.js';
```

---

Или экспортировать отдельные переменные или функции

```
function testExport(n) {
    return n + n;
}

const test_4 = ['Rus', 'Geo', 'Eng'];


export  {test_4, testExport};
```

И импорт

```
import {test_4, testExport} from './test-2.js';
```

> P.S. И да Qwertiy прав, расширение файла обязательно...

Comment: О, прикольно. Не знал про сервер. Обычные скрипты-то из соседних файлов нормально работают... А зачем так с модулями?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ты имеешь ввиду, почему не работает, если просто установить через `npm`?

Comment: Неа, просто вот такое: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r8YI.png. Получается что один и тот же файл как обычный скрипт доступен, а как модуль - ошибка CORS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2DhX.png

Comment: @Qwertiy, не могу сказать... я с таким не сталкивался...

Comment: Так ты ж сам в ответе написал, что оно работать не будет. А теперь "не сталкивался" о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy, я не сталкивался, что твой вариант будет работать.. У меня не работает как ты говоришь... А в моем ответе, все из лично практики....  Или же я тебя не верно понял... Ты говоришь, что у тебя без сервера работает...???

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105430/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-air).

Answer (score 0):

Расширение тоже надо указывать, если ты рассчитываешь, что браузер подтянет файл по сети.