# JavaScript модули, импорт экспорт

Tags: javascript, модули, импорт

Уже несколько часов не могу что то делать помогите ......

Значит в одном папке создаю два независимых файла, одна `html` а другой `js`, `js` файл ни к чему не привязан даже `html`, в нем я пишу `export let x = 1;`, а в `html` в теге `script` пишу `import {x} from './здесь имя js файла'` .....

Нечего не получается и в консоли появляется

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'-это ,

а когда в теге `script добавляю атрибут type="module"` появляются вот эти ошибки,

> "html.html:1 Access to script at
>   'file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/newFolderForJS/js' from origin 'null'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only
>   supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension,
>   https." ; "GET file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/newFolderForJS/js
>   net::ERR_FAILED"

помогите пж, как сделать что все работал??

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает import в javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1092554/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-import-%d0%b2-javascript)

Comment: А вы часом javaScript с node.js не перепутали?

Answer (score 1):

Запускайте html не просто открывая в браузере, а через локальный сервер или сразу ставьте на хостинг, тогда все заработает.

Comment: А это как делать? Я ток начинал изучать React js там через сервер и импорт и экспорт норм работает, но я вернулся к js чтоб боле подробно изучать импорт и экспорт, и бац, неработает

Comment: Скачайте любой локальный сервер openServer например, создайте там домен и скиньте ваши файлы туда, запускайте сервер и в браузере переходите по названию домена - профит )

Comment: Спасибо вам большое