# не работает import/export в JS(в браузере)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, импорт

У меня есть функция, которую я собрался переиспользовать, она в отдельном файле getsomestate.js:

```
function getSomeState(){
//some code
}

export default getSomeState;
```

И я хочу её импортировать во входной файл app.js. В app.js вверху пишу:

```
import getSomeState from "./getsomestate.js";
getSomeState();
```

Конечно, просто так оно работать не будет, поэтому в index.html я добавляю перед вызовом остальных скриптов:

```
<script type="module" src="src/js/getsomestate.js"  ></script>
...
<script src="src/js/app.js" type="text/babel" ></script>
```

И в результате я получаю(в консоли разработчика в браузере):
**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined** со ссылкой на строку с импортом.
когда запускаю LiveServer на локальном хосте и открываю там index.html.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что так импорты не будут работать никогда(и на это надо забить) и следует собирать проект через Webpack?

upd: такая проблема только со стороны клиентских скриптов(React JS).
На серверной части(Node.js) импорты работают отлично.

Comment: import/export - уже работают. Если ты получаешь ошибку `require is not defined` - значит ты запускаешь не тот код, который показываешь в вопросе.

Comment: Нужно больше подробностей. Как минимум что за сервер и что ещё кроме этого импорта есть

Comment: Команду "import" можно использовать только внутри скрипта, который объявлен с типом "module".

Comment: @ВикторКарев объявлен
`<script type="module" src="src/js/getsomestate.js"  ></script>` но не работает.

@AlexeyTen, VSCode+LiveServer. Импорт только один, он описан в вопросе и я специально его добавил, чтобы воспроизвести ошибку(и не захламлять вопрос кодом лишним)

@Grundy это тот код. Сейчас попробую отредактировать вопрос, чтобы было чуть понятнее.

Comment: [почитай](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1092554/Не-работает-import-в-javascript/1093180#1093180)

Comment: 1. app.js не объявлено с типом "module", поэтому в нём использовать import нельзя. 2. Скрипты, объявленные с типом "module", выполняются _после_ всех остальных скриптов, даже если ты их добавил перед ними.